# Save hardhat node state for later

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Is there a way to save your current local hardhat node state for later? Or do you have to restart every time you start up a new node?

Like:

```
yarn hardhat node --from-state ./state-dir
```

Or something

Comment: maybe you could run it on a docker container and open the ports for communications. An then you could stop and start the container instead of the node  (but not  100% sure if this will work)